# Abstracción de Logica para un filtrado de múltiples variables (R tidyverse)

Tags: r, filtro, lógica, tidyverse

El caso que planteo necesita una abstracción. Tengo un data frame con la siguiente estructura.

```
df <- tibble(
  var1 = c('2' ,NA ,'1'  ,'2'),
  var2 = c('2' ,NA ,NA ,'3'),
  var3 = c('1' ,NA ,NA ,'1'),
  var4 = c(NA,NA ,NA ,'2')
)
```

Mi problema es el siguiente. Quiero elaborar una nueva variable que recopile una serie de lógicas, para facilitar futuros filtrados (la llamaremos `mi_logica`).

`mi_logica` consiste en:

- si **cualquiera** de las variables contiene un **1**, y las demás variables no contienen ni un **2** ni un **3**, el resultado debería ser `"estudiable"`. Si son varios **1**, también. La regla básicamente es que no pueden haber 1 y a la vez un 2 o  un 3 en la misma fila.
- Si cualquiera de las variables contiene un **2** o un **3**, el resultado debería ser un `"No"`
- Si la fila contiene un **0**  o es toda **NA**, `"Si"`

Bajo estas premisas, el resultado final debería ser:

```
df <- tibble(
  var1 = c('2' ,NA ,'1'  ,'2'),
  var2 = c('2' ,NA ,NA ,'3'),
  var3 = c('1' ,0 ,NA ,'1'),
  var4 = c(NA,NA ,NA ,'2'),
  mi_logica = c('no','si','depende','no'))
```

Necesito que sea abstracto por que tengo bastante más que 4 variables, al punto que no me es rentable escribir todas las combinaciones. El problema está en que a la hora de armar las lógicas con `mutate` y `case_when`, al `across` no es excluyente y lo entiende todo por igual. y a pesar de que creo que tiene lógica, no obtengo el resultado deseado

---

Cosas que he probado:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(mi_logica= case_when(if_any(everything(), ~. =='1' & .!='2' &  .!='3' )~'estudiable'))
```

```
df %>% 
  mutate(mi_logica = case_when(if_any(everything(), ~.=='1' & !c('2','3')%in% .)~'estudiable'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas bien encaminado, pero tiene un problema de lógica:

```
if_any(everything(), ~. =='1' & .!='2' &  .!='3' )
```

Esto se traduce *"Si hay al menos una celda que sea un 1 y no sea un 2 o un 3"*, y un 1 ya hace cumplir toda la condición (ya que no es ni un 2 ni un 3).

Tienes que aplicar algunos `any` y `all` en cada subconjunto de verificación:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(mi_logica = case_when(
    if_any(everything(), ~ . == '1') &
    !if_any(everything(), ~ . %in% c('2','3')) ~ 'estudiable',
    if_any(everything(), ~ . %in% c('2','3')) ~ 'No',
    if_any(everything(), ~ . == '0') |
    if_all(everything(), ~ is.na(.)) ~ 'Si'
    ) 
  )
```

Comment: Vale, Creo entender el punto. Al ir los `if_any` separados, estos evalúan todas las combinaciones de condiciones entre ellas. Yo creía que la lógica ya estaba planteada para ello directamente. Pero efectivamente funciona, de modo que hay que poner mínimo dos para que evalúen las celdas por separado. Mil gracias ^^